# Testing an enum (custom error) with data from another module

Tags: testing, rust

I've created a custom error type using an enum to support multiple error conditions (omitted in example) but I am not able to test the following code without providing the data (in this case a `str::Utf8Error`) to the enum to perform a comparison.

```rust
use std::fmt;
use std::str;

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
pub enum ClaimsError {
    ParseError(str::Utf8Error),
    // Other variants omitted.
}

impl std::error::Error for ClaimsError {}

impl fmt::Display for ClaimsError {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        match self {
            ClaimsError::ParseError(ref err) => err.fmt(f),
        }
    }
}

pub fn from_slice(token: &[u8]) -> Result<&str, ClaimsError> {
    str::from_utf8(&token).map_err(|e| ClaimsError::ParseError(e))
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::{from_slice, ClaimsError};

    #[test]
    fn bad_token_fails() {
        assert_eq!(
            from_slice(&[0xF8]).unwrap_err(),
            ClaimsError::ParseError // <-- Here is the problem line.
        );
    }
}

fn main() {
    match from_slice(&[0xF8]) {
        Ok(_) => println!("great"),
        Err(ClaimsError::ParseError(err)) => println!("{}", err),
    }
}
```

Understandably the types do not match, thus causing the issue, so in an attempt to fix it I've tried changing the assertion to:

```rust
#[test]
fn bad_token_fails() {
    assert_eq!(
        from_slice(&[0xF8]).unwrap_err(),
        ClaimsError::ParseError(str::Utf8Error{})
    );
}
```

However it is not possible to create a `str::Utf8Error` this way because it contains only private fields. For the sake of my test I don't need to match the exact error, I am only concerned whether the error value returned from `from_slice` is of type `ClaimsError::ParseError`.

I've taken a look at the `Error` [trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/error/trait.Error.html) and in particular the `is` method stood out to me but I'm not sure if this is what I want or how to use it in this case. Any help solving this is appreciated.

[(link)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=25ea8d34e9e495f378a16df1c323c485) to a rust playground with the above code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `pattern matching` to `match` on the result of `from_slice(&[0xF8]).unwrap_err()`

```rust
#[test]
fn bad_token_fails() {
    match from_slice(&[0xF8]).unwrap_err() {
        ClaimsError::ParseError(_) => assert!(true),
        _ => assert!(false)
    }
}
```

This test succeeds if the result is of type `ClaimsError::ParseError` and fails if the result is of other types.

As @Cerberus stated, you could also use the `matches!` macro, to avoid using `assert!(true)` and `assert!(false)`:

```rust
#[test]
fn bad_token_fails() {
    assert!(matches!(
        from_slice(&[0xF8]),
        Err(ClaimsError::ParseError(_))
    ));
}
```

Comment: This is a really tidy way to solve the issue. Would you say this is an idiomatic way to write rust tests?

Comment: @tomasbasham I'm unsure about the `assert!(true)` part, but matching a pattern using `_` to omit the ignored patterns is very idiomatic

Comment: Thank you. This is super helpful.

Comment: More idiomatic might be `assert!(matches!( ... ))` - https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=18fc719e1d4271a44b2bfdc92f0f0565. The idea is the same, however.

Comment: @Cerberus thanks, I'll add this to my answer.